# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).parent(...).parent(...).children(...)[0].text is not a function

Tags: html, jquery

I have a row like this in a table:

```
<tr data-id="102" class="open">
    <td>Jonathan</td>
    <td class="title">Message</td>
    <td>2022-02-20 14:36:41</td>
    <td>
        <button id="btn-reply">Answer</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And by clicking on the button, I can get the value in the cell:

```
<td>Jonathan</td>
```

I have jQuery included and I'm trying to do it like this:

```
    $("#btn-reply").click(function() {
        console.log($(this).parent().parent().children()[0].text());
    })
```

As a result, I get this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).parent(...).parent(...).children(...)[0].text is not a function`

Comment: `[0]` gives you a DOM node rather than a jquery collection - *either* use [0].innerText or keep with jquery and use `.children().first().text()`

Comment: Or use `$(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").text()`

Comment: Note that Id are unique. I assume you do it have the same I’d in each row